# Slicing and updating non-contiguous indices in a DenseVector in Breeze

Tags: scala, numpy, scala-breeze

I want to do something like the following.

Equivalent code in NumPy

```
a = np.zeros(5)
a[np.array([1, 2, 4])] += [1, 2, 3]
a
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  3.])
```

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
val v = DenseVector.zeros[Double](5)
v(1, 2, 4) :+= DenseVector(1, 2, 3)

<console>:18: error: could not find implicit value for parameter op:breeze.linalg.operators.OpAdd.InPlaceImpl2[breeze.linalg.Vector[Double],breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Int]]
              v(1, 2, 4) += DenseVector(1, 2, 3)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please do not just say "it does not work". What didn't work? Compiler error? Run time error? Wrong result? What happened? What were you expecting?

Comment: And you can't just literally translate from Python to Scala! Your scala code doesn't really make any sense... what are you trying to do? Set the elements with indices 1, 2, and 4 to the values 1, 2, 3?

Comment: I've edited it, The thing is doing a slice like `v(1, 2, 4)` gives me a SliceVector which I'm not sure how to manipulate. The documentation is really sparse.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. Sorry I answered before you could edit your comment.

Comment: Figured it out. But I'm not sure it's the best way. `val indices = Array(1, 2, 4) val val_ = (1, 2, 3) indices.map(i => v(i) += val_(i))`

Comment: `(indices zip val_) map {case (i, x) =>  v(i)  = x}` maybe?

Comment: Thanks this is cleaner.

Comment: open a bug on breeze too, please. That should work.

Comment: Oh, it works! It was because of the int + double datatype